# How to store elements and number of appearances in Java

Tags: java

I got a newb question: I want to store some elements in a structure like( Object element, int count ), to say i have x number of element1 and y number of element2

For example:

```
dog,5
cat,4
toaster, 5
car, 1
spacecraft, 3
```

Is there a predifined Collection in Java that does this? or do i have to define one.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: a [`java.util.Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a `Map<K,V>` implementation, have a look at `HashMap<Object, Integer>`

Comment: isn't Map used to store mappings, like a dictionary for example where keys are unique? I'm looking for something where i'd do .add(cat) and it would check if cat exists and if it does, then do catNumber++ else insert cat,1

Comment: @AlexDoro Yes it is; if you want an *active* object then, yes, as you said in your question, you have to define a new class with your counting logic.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `HashMap<String,Integer>` storing the `String` as the key and the number of occurrences as an Integer.

Comment: isn't Map used to store mappings, like a dictionary for example where keys are unique? I'm looking for something where i'd do .add(cat) and it would check if cat exists and if it does, then do catNumber++ else insert cat,1

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Map generics

```
Map<Object,Integer> l=new HashMap<Object,Integer>();
```

Comment: isn't Map used to store mappings, like a dictionary for example where keys are unique? I'm looking for something where i'd do .add(cat) and it would check if cat exists and if it does, then do catNumber++ else insert cat,1

Comment: @AlexDoro yes map is used for the same.